# How to drop multiple rows with specific names in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of elements like x = ["a","b","c"] and I want to drop all rows which contain these elements.

column name = "name"

How can I use a list format for drop these rows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using isin ?

Comment: yeah I used "~" and it worked. Thanks.